# Idiomatic way to map single object

Tags: kotlin

Is this the idiomatic way to perform a short-circuiting search and map the result to a `Boolean`?

```
val foos = mutableListOf<Foo>()
...
fun fooBar(bar: Bar) = if (null != foos.find { it.bar == bar }) true else false
```

Basically, I was looking for something along the lines of

```
fun Any?.exists() = null != this
fun fooBar(bar: Bar) = foos.find { it.bar == bar }.exists()
```

which seems like a useful pattern for anything that might return `null`.

**EDIT:**

I settled on writing a simple extension function similar to `filterIsInstance()`:

```
inline fun <reified R> Iterable<*>.findIsInstance(): R? {
    for (element in this) if (element is R) return element
    return null
}
```

Example usage:

```
val str = list.findIsInstance<String>() ?: return
```

Comment: By the way, I don't think it's ever a good idea to do `if (<condition>) true else false`, when `<condition>` alone means exactly the same!

Comment: Yes, that's true, and I think IntelliJ would have suggested that. I just made this up to ask the question. (If you look at my `exists` function, that's exactly what I did.) It turns out my idea to use `exists` or `isNotNull` (as I renamed it later) isn't a great idea. The compiler can't infer that the object isn't `null` even after the test, so its usage becomes problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html), which returns true if any of the elements match the given predicate, and is short-circuiting

```
fun fooBar(bar: Bar) = foos.any { it.bar == bar }
```